# pip broken; v9.0.1 installed but setuptools required 8.1.1

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Haven't had any problem in the past or made any changes recently, but as of this morning, doing anything with pip, include just running "pip" with no arguments results in an excepting saying that setuptools requires 8.1.1 but 9.0.1 is installed - so I can't upgrade setuptools or downgrade pip.

```
$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 659, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 967, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 858, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 9.0.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==8.1.1'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mobiglas/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3017, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3030, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 661, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 674, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 853, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==8.1.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: Try get_pip.py :[install_pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use easy_install to re-install pip

```
$ easy_install-3.5 pip 
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 9.0.1
Adding pip 9.0.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip3 script to /home/.../bin
Installing pip3.5 script to /home/.../bin
Installing pip script to /home/.../bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```